# Octave: A(~isnan(A)) results vector containing NaNs?

Tags: matlab, octave

May be I don't get a basic thing, but I recently discovered this behaviour, and by now I don't understand what's happening:

```
A = [3 NaN .12 NaN NaN 9]
A =

            3          NaN         0.12          NaN          NaN            9

>> nansA = isnan(A)
nansA =

  0  1  0  1  1  0

>> nnansA = ~isnan(A)
nnansA =

  1  0  1  0  0  1

>> nnansA1 = ~isnan(A(1:end))
nnansA1 =

  1  0  1  0  0  1

>> nnansA2 = ~isnan(A(2:end))
nnansA2 =

  0  1  0  0  1

>> AnnansA1 = A(~isnan(A(1:end)))
AnnansA1 =

            3         0.12            9

>> **AnnansA2 = A(~isnan(A(2:end)))
AnnansA2 =

          NaN          NaN
```

What is happening here?

Does this happen in Matlab too?

I would expect something like `... AnnansA2 = 0.12 9`

Comment: `0  1  0  0  1` so the second and fifth entry is true, the second and fifth entry of `A` are `NaN`. So everything es expected.

Comment: The title is your question is actually not correct, as the command that doesn't work for you is not the one in the title.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is that you're indexing `A` with a logical array of a different size and expect the indexing to not start at the beginning.

Let's deconstruct, from the inside:

```
>> A = [3 NaN .12 NaN NaN 9]
A =

   3.0000      NaN   0.1200      NaN      NaN   9.0000

>> # B a new array, with 5 elements (A had 6 elements)
>> B = A(2:end)
B =

      NaN   0.1200      NaN      NaN   9.0000

>> # mask is a logical array with 5 elements, like B, and not 6, like A.
>> # mask knows nothing about A or B.  It simply "selects" (indexes) the
>> # 1st, 3rd, and 4th element of any array.
>> mask = isnan (B)
mask =

  1  0  1  1  0

>> # Invert the mask, now "selects" the 2nd and 5th element of any array.
>> not_mask = ! mask
not_mask =

  0  1  0  0  1

>> # Return the 2nd and 5th element of A.
>> A(not_mask)
ans =

   NaN   NaN
```

I think you're surprised by the behaviour because you expect that `A(2:end)` "remembers" that it comes from `A` to index the right "region" of `A`.  This does not happen, it's just a logical array that "remembers" nothing from which array it came (and often used to index different arrays).

As a side note, and answering one of your questions, Matlab behaviour is the same as Octave.

Anyway, what you're doing looks a bit odd, maybe do this instead:

```
A(! isnan (A))(2:end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're off by one.

You need to do `AnnansA2 = A(~isnan(A(1:end)))`

If you want to return only the last two non-nans, index the result like;

```
ananIdxs = ~isnan(A)
AnnansA2 = A(ananIdxs(2:end))
```

Comment: That would only work if `ananIdxs = find(~isnan(A))`. In your example, `ananIdxs` is a logical array (a set of Boolean values), and the result would be the same as in the OP (`A(ananIdxs(2:end)) == A(~isnan(A(2:end)))`)

Comment: Thx for your answer. Unfortunatly I don't get it:  ```ananIdxs = ~isnan(A)
ananIdxs =

  1  0  1  0  0  1

>> A(ananIdxs(1:end))
ans =

            3         0.12            9

>> A(ananIdxs(2:end))
ans =

          NaN          NaN
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).